# Trying to run a query that will show us the percentages of outbound leads vs. inbound leads

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

So far our code is below but it is giving us an error

```
Select LeadSource, (count(‘Inbound’) from Lead_T * 100 / select count (LeadSource) from Leads_T)) as percent 
Where LeadID in( select stage
       From opportunities_T  
       Where Opportunities_T.stage = ‘7-Closed/Won’)
```

Table 1:

```
create table Opportunities_T
(Executive varchar(50) not null,
 AccountName varchar(150) not null,
 Stage varchar(50) not null,
 OpAmount int not null,
 CloseDate date not null,
 AccountStatus varchar(15) not null,
 LeadID int not null,
 constraint Opportunities_PK primary key (LeadID, AccountName),
 constraint Opportunities_FK1 foreign key (LeadID) references Leads_T(LeadID),
 constraint Opportunities_FK2 foreign key (AccountName) references Account_T(AccountName));
```

Table 2:

```
create table Leads_T
(Contact varchar(25),
Company varchar(100),
Title varchar(150),
LeadSource varchar(30),
BDR varchar(50),
LeadID int,
constraint Leads_PK primary key (LeadID));
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your query makes no sense.

Comment: You can't use curly quotes in code. It has to be ASCII single or double quotes.

Comment: How do you tell whether a lead is inbound or outbound?

Comment: `count('inbound')` is the same as `count(*)`. And `count(LeadSource)` is the same as `count(*)` if the column is never `NULL`.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: You can tell if a lead is outbound or inbound because that is the "LeadSource"

Comment: This is the error:Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'LeadSource' in 'field list'